# double fork causes socket in original parent to break

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fork

I do a double fork (fork, then the child forks again, I wait for the child, the grandchild is handled by init) in a process and after the child has closed I try to read from a socket that I had open in the parent previous to the fork. The read fails every time I run the program.

The message is being sent using sendto() which returns an error code of ENOENT.

Should this be working or am I [10]?

Here is the code in the function that forks:

```
uint8_t
upgrade(
        char *server,
        char *file)
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;

    int status;

    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        /* Fork error */
        log("FAILED: First fork() failed");
    }
    else if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        /* First child */
        if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
        {
            /* Fork error */
            log("FAILED: Second fork() failed");

            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pid2 == 0)
        {
            /*
                        execl("/usr/sbin/system_upgrade",
                                    "system_upgrade", NULL);
             */
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            /* Second parent ie. First child
             * Note: Exit cleanly so that second child
             * gets reparented to init, and we avoid a zombie process */

            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* First parent, wait for first child to exit */
        if (waitpid (pid1, &status, 0) != pid1)   
        {
            log("FAILED: waitpid() failed");
        }

    } /* FORK */

    return OK;
}
```

edit: removed extra bracket, fixed indentation, marked it as code again

Comment: I'm more concerned if there is an issue I should be watching for or my code is the problem.Assume the program opens a socket to another program normally, and the child and grandchild processes close immediately after opening using exit(0).

Comment: The child process inherits the socket, so probably it's the code to have some issue.

Comment: You should be using `_exit()` rather than `exit()` in the child processes, but I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: caf, better add an answer. You got it.

Comment: ENOENT:  
A component of the pathname does not name an existing file or the pathname is an empty string.  
  
Looks like the socket was being closed. I thought the 3 processes would each have a reference to the FD so the system would keep it open, but I guess that wasn't the case?

Comment: @Terminal This is not a socket error. Are you just inspecting errno randomly, or did you really get a -1 from recv() or send() first?

Comment: @EJP sendto() returned a -1. ENOENT was the value indicated in errno, and that is the description given on the sendto(3) man page. That is about all I know about it. Does it indicate something other than a socket error?

Comment: @Terminal That would indicate that the target address in `sendto()` was no longer valid, and probably also that you were using an `AF_UNIX` socket. Is that the case? and is this TCP or UDP? If TCP you should use `send()` or `sendmsg()`.

Comment: @EJP Yes, was using AF_UNIX. What I still might be confused on is why the target address was no longer valid. It seems to me that the socket would have had to be closed. Thanks for taking the time to discuss this with me, btw. Wish I could at least up vote your comments.

Comment: When spawning helper processes (fork + execv), it is a good idea not to inherit all filedescriptors to the children. Please read man page for fcntl and F_GETFD / F_GETFD / FD_CLOEXEC